# Progress bar is not updating on another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to delete files and sub folders from specific folder, while deleting the files progress bar should show progress bar which is on the another form.

I have taken background worker for this. progress bar value is changing as excepted but on screen progress bar is not displaying updating percentage.

I am using `visual studio 2005`. Because this is old project.

```
private void EmptyFolder(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, long totalSize, frmProgress frmProgressLbl, ref long deletedSize)
{
    short percent;
    //long deletedSize=0;
    try
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                deletedSize += file.Length;
                file.Delete();
                percent = Convert.ToInt16((deletedSize * 100) / totalSize);
                frmProgressLbl.Percent = percent;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subfolder in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            EmptyFolder(subfolder, totalSize,frmProgressLbl,ref deletedSize);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

**And below is code on form where progress bar is.**

```
public partial class frmProgress : Form
{
    private short percent;
    public short Percent { set { percent = value; } }
    private BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
    public frmProgress()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this.bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        this.bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
        this.bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void frmProgress_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = "Deleting Files...";
        this.bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Value = percent;
    }
}
```

Your help may appreciated.

Comment: Do not write empty try/catch You will never see why your program fails.

Comment: See: [ProgressChangedEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx). If you read the MSDN definition of the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll find a complete sample code that does exactly what you're trying to do with yours (btw, you're calling `RunWorkerAsync()` twice but the worker method, `EmptyFolder()`, is never referenced).

Comment: Your BackgroundWorker finishes its work after executing that one line in DoWork. You will have to keep the BackgroundWorker alive.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of pain - never ever write `catch (Exception ex)` and especially not with `{ }`. Only ever catch an exception if it is specific (i.e. not `Exception`) and only if you can meaningfully handle it.

Comment: @Nandu the BGW is meant to *do* the work in the background, not update the form "in the background". You can't modify the UI from another thread and that's it. You should put the *loop* inside `DoWork` and use the `ProgressChanged` event to report progress.

Comment: @Nandu even better, don't use BGW at all. You could use `await Task.Run()=>file.Delete();` inside the loop and report progress right after the `await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieving with the help of following code

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start your task
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {                
                #region Write logic to delete files in this region

                var totalFiles = 100;

                for (int i = 1; i <= totalFiles; i++)
                {                    
                    // Report progress
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((i * totalFiles) / 100);

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                } 

                #endregion                
        }

private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {                
                // Update prgores bar
                progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;                
        }  

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {                
                // Do further process when your task is completed                
        }
```

Comment: If you remove the extremely bad `try`/`catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }`  then I'll up-vote. Right now this code is a recipe for creating bugs.

Comment: Yes your are right. I know that it is a bad practice to write try catch block in every method or event.

Comment: Code-only answers aren't considered good answers. Why does this answer the OP's question? How does this differ from the original code? I won't ask "why use BGW at all", or mention the `catch{}`

Comment: In a question he is updating progress bar in 'DoWork' event ' this.progressBar1.Value = percent;' so it will throw cross thread exception so the proper approach to update ui in 'ProgressChanged' event

Comment: @AdvaitBaxi explain that in the *answer itself*. And clean up the answer btw, there's absolutely no need to hide exceptions.

Comment: @AdvaitBaxi - Then why do it?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the method of Deleting the files on frmProgress  form and it resolved my problem.

Thanks to all of you.